# Why Button click redirection for another xml page is not working?

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, android-manifest

I looked in to everything before ask this. I am implementing an application and new to android, I need to redirect to my `mapview xml` when `login button click`. So i have written the `intent` plus made the `activity in manifest` file and tried writing codes every possible different way. And the code doesn't give any errors. But my `emulator stops` after launching.
I know something is wrong but I can't figure it out. Any idea why that happens?

here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.loginbtn:
                    Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, MapView.class);
                    startActivity (intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;}
                }
             }
          );
        }
     }
                /*if(username.getText().toString()==""&&password.getText().toString()=="")
                {

                     Intent i= new Intent("com.example.shaz.MAPVIEW");
                     startActivity(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    txt.setText("False");


                }
            */
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myname"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myname.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <activity
            android:name=".mapView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.myname.MAPVIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFUALT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have also created an xml file for map called map_view in my layouts.

So in every where I searched this is how they say new intent is creating .

And the emulator works fine if I do something else than this redirection. SO what ever problem I got is within this redirection part.

Comment: You need it to be android:name=".MapView" in your activity, not ".mapView". Past that, what errors are you getting?

Comment: @zgc7009 no it doesn't work. I tried earlier and now also.

Comment: Without knowing what errors you are getting or why your application is crashing it will be hard. What does MapView.class look like? And it's xml

Comment: I don't get any errors. It just stops in the middle ssaying unfortunatly emulator stopped working

Comment: Try it on a physical device. May help at least get a full crash log

Comment: DEFAULT is spelled incorrectly in your Manifest.

Comment: @user3621469 Please accept my answer.  I wasn't 100% sure that would fix it at first, so I left a comment.  I need the rep to put a bounty on my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEFAULT is spelled incorrectly in your Manifest

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFUALT" />
```

for this:

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Comment: I got the answer through a comment before this was posted :)